# USACO Arithmetic Progressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded

The problem I'm solving is:

> given a length of an arithmetic progression, and a limit to the
> terms (see below), find all progressions that work.
>
> All terms of the progressions must be of the form a²+b², and
> 0 ≤ a²+b² ≤ limit.

I have the following code:

```py
from math import ceil
with open('ariprog.in') as fin:
    ariLen = int(fin.readline().strip())
    ariLim = int(fin.readline().strip())
def generate(bound):
    max_len=((bound**2)*2)+1
    parity = [0]*max_len
    for i in range(bound+1):
        for j in range(bound+1):
            parity[i**2+j**2] = 1
    return parity

parity = generate(ariLim)
lenpar = len(parity)
big_mama_ar = []
# print(lenpar)
for a in range(lenpar-1):
    if parity[a] == 1:
        for d in range(1, ceil((lenpar-a)/(ariLen-1))):
            for n in range(1, ariLen):
                # print('a:', a)
                # print('d:', d)
                # print('n:', n)
                if parity[a+n*d] != 1:
                    break
            else:
                big_mama_ar.append((a,d))
                pass
big_mama_ar.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
with open('ariprog.out', 'w') as fout:
    if big_mama_ar == []:
        fout.write('NONE\n')
    else:
        for i in big_mama_ar:
            fout.write(str(i[0])+' '+str(i[1])+'\n')
```

This code times out on my grader when `ariLen` is 21 and `ariLim` is 200. The time limit is 5 seconds, and on my computer, it takes 22 seconds.
ariprog.in is

> 21
>
> 200

Comment: How can we run this code? What's in that *ariprog.in* file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to CodeReview!

### Whitespace

The PEP8 standard, and consequently most Python linting tools, will recommend that you add another linebreak before your function definitions, plus some whitespace around your operators, etc. I won't detail this exhaustively; you're best to use the IDE of your choice - PyCharm is a reasonable one that is helpful for this.

### Type hinting

`bound` is probably an integer, so add `: int` after it. It probably returns an `int` as well.

### Subroutines

Put your global-scoped code into subroutines for ease of maintenance, legibility and testing.

### Redundant `pass`

That `pass` isn't needed.

### Use format strings

This:

```
str(i[0])+' '+str(i[1])+'\n'
```

can be

```
f'{i[0]} {i[1]}\n'
```

### Simplify some math

This:

```
((bound**2)*2)+1
```

can be

```
2 * bound**2 + 1
```

due to operator precedence.

### Truthiness

This:

```
if parity[a+n*d] != 1:
```

can be

```
if not parity[a + n*d]:
```

because 0 is falsey.

### camel_case

`ariLen` is more commonly written `ari_len` in Python.

Comment: Not just "because 0 is falsey" - but because 1 is the only truthy value we'll get.  If `parity` could be 2, for example, then those tests wouldn't be equivalent.